# How to handle SQL Server's Linked-Server Error 18452?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I'd like to connect Server A (SQL Server 2008 R2) and Server B (SQL Server 2017) by Linked Server.

I created the Linked-Server successfully as below script, and I'm sure to connect from Server B to Server A by SQL Server Management Studio with the same user/password.

However, I got the error 18452, windows authentication error, even though tried to connect by SQL Server ID/PW.

```
-- Create Linked-Server @ Server B, SQL Server 2017
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver         
       @server = 'TEST',            
       @srvproduct = 'SQL Server',          
       @provider = 'SQLNCLI',            
       @datasrc = 'XX.XX.XX.XX (Server A IP Address)';          

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin           
       @rmtsrvname = 'TEST',            
       @useself = 'FALSE',          
       @locallogin = 'user_name',           
       @rmtuser = 'user_name',          
       @rmtpassword = 'password'; 

-- test sql
select * from test.test_db.dbo.test_table;

-- Error Message
Login failed for user '<user_name>'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: ["Login failed for user" error message when you log on to SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-my/help/555332/login-failed-for-user-error-message-when-you-log-on-to-sql-server)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for your comment. I understand log on failure with linked-server, even though with the valid user account and password. And nothing wrong with net work since I can log on by remote access with Management Studio.

Comment: Hi @Sachiko. Have you solved this? I encounter the same problem.